# Response.write in IIS integrated mode

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, integrated-pipeline-mode

I have been working on an `asp.net` project that must work in integrated mode on IIS 7.5.

When I use `Response.write("sometext")`, `IIS` wraps my texts with waste `HTML` tags.

Look at this code:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearContent();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<html>");
        sb.Append("<head>");
        sb.Append("</head>");
        sb.AppendFormat("<body>");
        sb.AppendFormat("some text");
        sb.Append("</body>");
        sb.Append("</html>");
        Response.Write(sb.ToString());
        Response.End();

}
```

I exepct receive this from server:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
sometext
</body>
</html>
```

but the server gives me this:

```
 <html> 
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <pre>
      <html><head></head><body>sometext</body></html>
 </pre>
 </body>
 </html>
```

What's the problem??

Application works fine in `VS web developer server` or `IIS` ( in classic mode ).

Comment: Do you have html in your aspx file?  Is there a Master Page defined?

Comment: The project has both aspx (with html) and master page but I put these codes in global.asax file

Comment: Yes, but you are rendering a page.. Default.aspx or whatever it is.  That page will render its master page by default, which probably is where you're getting the head and pre from

Comment: here is scenario :
i request a URL that doesn't exist on server . then before the server can back a 404 error page i generate a dynamic page according to inputted URL.
so we have no .aspx page and no master page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after two days accidentally i founded if use 
    Response.Flush();
command the IIS can't wrap the response